# Fail to clear cache with Symfony on Vagrant

Tags: symfony, vagrant

I'm using Vagrant on Windows with a box created on PuPHPet (Debian 7 and PHP 5.4). I installed a new project with Symfony 2 and there is some errors to clear the cache like "Cannot rename" or "Failed to remove directory".

I used the default configuration but also tried to:

- enable NSF
- follow the "Setting up Permissions" part on the [Symfony guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup)
- specify www-data as user/group for /var/www
- change vagrant as apache user/group

and nothing changed, still the same errors.

How can I set the right permissions on the Symfony's cache with Vagrant?

Thank you

Comment: when you have changed `vagrant` as apache `user/group` you should also specify `vagrant` as user/group for your `/var/www` also (if you have changed it to `www-data` earlier).

Comment: Iam not familiar with PhPHPNet.. but I am assuming you are using synced folders. Does you vagrant file contains 
owner: "www-data", group: "www-data", mount_options: ["dmode=755,fmode=644"]. You may try also experimenting with ["dmode=777,fmode=777"]. You may configure symfony console command on windows machine and execute from windows. Also try to delete folder inside cache (eg old_dev )from virtual box as root if you can't it may be a bug with vm provider (eg problem with virtualBox )

Comment: I tried with mount_options: ["dmode=777,fmode=777"] and still the same problem. If I clear the cache from windows, there is another error with Symfony where it mixes Windows and Linux paths: "ContextErrorException: Warning: file_get_contents(E:/www/test/app/Resources\views/base.html.twig): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Templating/Storage/FileStorage.php line 32"

Comment: I've also just tried similar setup (local vmbox) and I have so many problems with symfony when sources are stored on windows It's difficult to count them all. Also symfony cache related classes and others have statemets like if ( PHP_WINDOWS_VERSION_BUILD ) { ; } ( which doesn't look good if we need kind of mix  different file systems )

Comment: The only "sollution" which works for me is to have files (not synced) on Windows and using automatic deployment/sync tools which usually coming with IDE.

Comment: Any new solutions for this?

Comment: Any solutions for this? I have the same problem even when using Vagrant 1.7.2.

Answer (score 2):

PHPStorm (there's Community Edition) has auto upload feature, which I successfully used for Vagrant file sharing. However you need to disable Vagrant's file sharing (NFS doesn't work with Windows out of the box anyway).

This is one say sync, thus you need to clear cache from inside of box.

---

**Settings > Deployment** (path to settings page depends on IDE version) add deployment server:

Connection tab:

```
Type: SFTP
Host: box IP
Port: 22
Username: vagrant
Password: vagrant
```

> If I recall correctly PuPHPet disables password login in favor of key
>   based access, so use appropriate method (key was publicly stored in puphpet's repo).

Mapping tab:

```
Local path: project root locally
Deployment path: project root in box
```

**Settings > Deployment > Options:**

```
Upload automatically: Always
Upload external changes: Yes
Delete target items when source does not exist: Yes
```

---

There's NFS Vagrant plugin for Windows, but I could not get it to run as of March 2015.

There's also `rsync` sync method from Vagrant which offers one way sync as well, but I liked PHPStorm's autoupload more.

Comment: Really helpful. Thank you.